# ODI Log and Error files are empty

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-data-integrator, essbase

Hi I am trying to load data using ODI where my source is flat files and target is Hyperion Essbase but it is getting failed and if I try to see the ODI Log and Error files they are empty.
Can anyone help me regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your code to question.

Comment: """select   CASE WHEN C1_CODE='Basic' THEN 'A31110' 
WHEN C1_CODE='CCA' THEN 'A31140' ELSE END    "Account",'BegBalance' "Period",'No Department' "Department", C2_GRADE_NAME "Grade",C3_PSM_POSN_NO "Position",'FY16'    "Year",'Actual'    "Scenario",'Final'    "Version",C4_AIRPORT_NAME    "Entity",C5_PAY_VALUE    "Data" from "C$_0HRPLAN_PLAN1Data"  where(1=1)""" srcCx = odiRef.getJDBCConnection("SRC") stmt =srcCx.createStatement() srcFetchSize=30 #stmt.setFetchSize(srcFetchSize) stmt.setFetchSize(1)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug an ODI job is to go in the Operator navigator in ODI Studio. There you will see the result of the execution, with more or less details depending on the log level you choose at execution time. The higher the log level is, the more information you will have.

The log files in ODI Studio only contains errors encountered by the GUI while designing your jobs, it doesn't give much information about the runtime.